# URL fetcher and parser for XML feeds

Tags: parsing, haskell, xml, io

Here is a program that will parse and print XML feed URLs. I want to reuse most of it to add post date to each link. This adds a new concern of CLI and output formatting on top of parsing and (poor) error handling. I wonder how much of this code has enough value to put is in a wrapper utility and how much should be simply scrapped and basically left to user.

I also wonder whether `Text.Feed` has enough value to use it (it's just XML represented by datatype) and I'm just traversing it.

```
module Main (main, extract) where

import Text.Feed.Import
import Text.Feed.Query (getItemLink, getFeedItems)
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

validate x = case x of
  Nothing -> error
  Just v  -> const v

extract selector feedString = selector $ (flip validate) "feed parsing failed" . parseFeedString $ feedString

main :: IO ()
main = do
  feedString <- getContents
  mapM_ putStrLn $ extract selector feedString
    where
      selector = getFeedItems >=> (maybeToList . getItemLink)
```